# Ionic 2 : Disable "Ok" button on keyboard in a form

Tags: android, ios, forms, angular, ionic2

I build an Ionic 2 app with form. In my forms, I can have input type "text", and obsiously, it open device keyboard. 
But, when I touch "Ok" button on the keyboard it do my submit form action.

I don't want my keyboard to do this, I just want to close keyboard when button is touch.

Somebody have any idea to override this button ?

[image: Key board in form]

Answer (score 1):

What I did was a simple check if the keyboard is open on the method called on submitting the form.

```
if (this.keyboard.isOpen()) {
   this.keyboard.close();
   return;
}
```

that prevents the go button from actually submitting but instead closes the keyboard. Remember to add the keyboard to the constructor - public keyboard: Keyboard 
and imports - import { Keyboard } from 'ionic-angular';